# Умные указатели в С++(Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, smart-pointer

Здравствуйте, недавано познакомился с Qt, но визникли некоторые проблемы по поводу использования умных указателей вместес QTableView, вот пример кода:

```
MainFormSettings::MainFormSettings(Ui::MainForm* mainForm) {
    ui = mainForm;
    administratorsService = new AdministratorsService;
    modelAdministrators = new QStandardItemModel;

    QStringList headers;
    headers.append("Логин");
    headers.append("Пароль");
    modelAdministrators->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers);
    ui->tableAdministrators->setModel(modelAdministrators);

    QMap<QString, QString> administrators = administratorsService->getAllAdministrators();
    size_t row = 0;

    for (auto it = administrators.begin(); it != administrators.end(); it++) {
        QString login = it.key();
        QString password = it.value();
        QStandardItem* itemLogin = new QStandardItem(login);
        modelAdministrators->setItem(row, 0, itemLogin);
        QStandardItem* itemPassword = new QStandardItem(password);
        modelAdministrators->setItem(row, 1, itemPassword);
        row++;
    }
}
```

Так все прекрасно работает. Как видно из кода заполняю таблицу администраторов(лоиг и пароль) из базы данных, но потом при перезагрузки таблицы новыйми данными память же придется освободить, в связи с этим решил воспользоваться умными указателями:

```
MainFormSettings::MainFormSettings(Ui::MainForm* mainForm) {
    ui = mainForm;
    administratorsService = new AdministratorsService;
    modelAdministrators = new QStandardItemModel;

    QStringList headers;
    headers.append("Логин");
    headers.append("Пароль");
    modelAdministrators->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers);
    ui->tableAdministrators->setModel(modelAdministrators);

    QMap<QString, QString> administrators = administratorsService->getAllAdministrators();
    size_t row = 0;

    for (auto it = administrators.begin(); it != administrators.end(); it++) {
        QString login = it.key();
        QString password = it.value();
        std::unique_ptr<QStandardItem> itemLogin = std::make_unique<QStandardItem>(login);
        modelAdministrators->setItem(row, 0, itemLogin.get());
        std::unique_ptr<QStandardItem> itemPassword = std::make_unique<QStandardItem>(password);
        modelAdministrators->setItem(row, 1, itemPassword.get());
        row++;
    }
}
```

Но когда я использую это, просто в таблицу ничего не выводится, по видимому память освобождается... Может кто-ниубдь подскажет в чем проблема и способ ее решения? Заранее спасибо

Comment: 1. Время жизни вашего unique_ptr указателя ограничено рамками цикла. Он умрёт когда цикл завершится. 2. В Qt не надо думать об очистке элементов QTableView, он сам всё прекрасно удаляет. Проверьте путём создания записей и использования setRowsCount(0); в цикле.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используемый вами тип `QStandardItemModel` сам освободит в [своем деструкторе](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#dtor.QStandardItemModel) все лежащие в нем объекты когда придет время; дополнительно освобождать что бы то ни было не только бесполезно, но и ошибочно.

Использовать unique_ptr для хранения промежуточных объектов можно - но только в более сложных случаях, когда вы не сразу передаете владение ими в другой класс. Для этого можно использовать метод release:

```
std::unique_ptr<QStandardItem> itemLogin = std::make_unique<QStandardItem>(login);
// ...
modelAdministrators->setItem(row, 0, itemLogin.release());
```

Но в вашем случае это избыточно, ведь между созданием объекта и добавлением его в `modelAdministrators` нет никакого лишнего кода.

Где и правда следует применять умные указатели - так это в вашем классе, для того чтобы автоматически освободить `QStandardItemModel`:

```
private:
std::unique_ptr<QStandardItemModel> modelAdministrators;
```

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае Вам не нужны умные указатели: когда вы добавляете `QStandardItem` в модель, то уже модель отвечает за удаление своих элементов.

В случае с `std::unique_ptr`, вы добавляете в модель указатель на данные, затем область видимости `std::unique_ptr` заканчивается и указатель удаляется, модель в с свою очередь видит что элемент удален и по-этому не использует его для отображения.

Comment: очень хороший  ответ

Answer (score 3):

Qt и стандартные умные указатели обычно не совместимы. В данном случае метод `setItem` принимает владение объектом, на который указывает переданный указатель. В других случаях могут применяться [умные указатели qt](https://wiki.qt.io/Smart_Pointers).